# How do you read Apache vhost information (PerlSetVar) in CGI scripts?

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, vhosts

Is there a sane way of accessing vhost (PerlSetVar) information from a CGI script?

Can't find anything when I do a search.

Comment: Haha, ended up doing that as an easy, ugly hack - at least it's confined. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try duplicating all the `PerlSetVar` settings as `PerlSetEnv` settings and then just pull them out of `%ENV` in the CGI scripts. Yes, this would be an ugly hack but an ugly hack that works is better than no solution at all (just be sure to have a shower after you do it).